# How to build a keyword-related graph from an initial input keyword?

Tags: twitter, graph, keyword, text-mining, mining

As a beginner text-miner, I really want to ask for advices/guidelines on graph mining, based on a real need of me: build a keyword-related graph from an initial input keyword.

I know the topic is relatively large, so I want to do it for Twitter first:
I have harvested a tweet corpus of the keywords "survey" and "market". I want to mine from that corpus to build a graph of keywords related to "survey" or "market".

I have tried using NodeXL and NLTK but I couldn't do what I want.

Comment: NodeXL can show you the most frequent hashtags, words, word pairs, and URLs for the entire graph and for any clusters you have. What weren't you able to do?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what your goals are, but here are some suggestions.
 You have several options on the type of graph you can build.

- you can build a bipartite graph with tweets on one side and key words on the other.

  you could build a network where the vertices are tweets and the edges represents a common term

  or you could build a network where the vertices are key words and edges represent that the keywords appeared in the same tweet

It all depends on what you are trying to discover.

Take a look at http://www.kdnuggets.com/websites/twitter-analytics-data-mining.html for some suggestions

There are also a number of excellent paper on graph-based mining of Twitter publish by the IEEE and/or ACM